# error en dato excel desde un csv con epplus

Tags: c#, excel, csv

tengo fichero csv que tiene como uno de sus datos 829/10/17 y usando epplus para convertir a excel lo cambia a este dato -390883 a pesar que fuerzo la columna a tipo texto, ya probe tambien en perzonalidad y general y sigue haciendolo, podrian ayudarme

ojo no es tipo date, es un string y en esa columna no siempre vendra el dato de esa forma. es decir puede venir sin las barras.

```
   string excelFileName = rutasalida + "Resultado " + fechafilename + "-" + horatotalfilename + ".xlsx";


        string worksheetsName = "Hoja1";

        bool firstRowIsHeader = false;

        var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
        format.Delimiter = ';';
        format.EOL = "\n";
        format.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
       // format.DataTypes = new eDataTypes[] { eDataTypes.Number, eDataTypes.String };



        format.SkipLinesEnd = 1;



        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName)))
        {


            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
            worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 20;
            worksheet.Cells["A1:BI"].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;

            worksheet.Cells["N:N"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["W:W"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";


            worksheet.Cells["AD:AD"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["AF:AF"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["AL:AL"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["AN:AN"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["AS:AS"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["AU:AU"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["BA:BA"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["BB:BB"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
            worksheet.Cells["BF:BF"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";

            worksheet.Cells["J:J"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
            worksheet.Cells["k:k"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
            worksheet.Cells["L:L"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;
            worksheet.Cells["M:M"].Style.Numberformat.Format = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern;

            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(csvFileName), format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None, firstRowIsHeader);

            package.Save();

        }
```

Comment: Una forma de forzar una columna como texto es anteponer al dato una comilla simple , `' ` a la hora de generar el csv.

Comment: el dato del campo no puede ser alterado, pero ya lo he resuelto  haciendo un array de formatos  en el format, gracias a todos y un saludo